# How to write a reg ex for show vlan

Tags: python, regex

Below is my stab at it, but it is not getting it right.  There is a lot more in my "text" file, but I would like to get the vlan and ports:
Attempt for Python:

```
([\d])+\W+[a-zA-Z]+\W+[A-Za-z]+\W+|[\w+]+([\d])/([\d])
```

Output:

> Vlan 1 Et0/1
>   Vlan 1 Et0/3
>   Vlan 1 Et0/4
>   Vlan 1 Et0/5
>   Vlan 1 Et0/6
>   Vlan 1 Et0/7
>   Vlan 2 Et0/0
>   Vlan 3 Et0/2

From this......

```
asa#  Show switch vlan

VLAN Name                             Status    Ports

---- -------------------------------- --------- -----------------------------

1    inside                           up        Et0/1, Et0/3, Et0/4, Et0/5

                                                Et0/6, Et0/7

2    outside                          up        Et0/0

3    dmz                              up        Et0/2
```

Comment: This did something funny to the way it is displayed.  Et0/6, ET0/7 should be right under Et0/4 and 5. and the output each starts with Vlan x

Comment: Fixed your formatting. Are they really all two lines apart?

Comment: Thank you.  Most of it will be just like pictured.  But I suppose, the number of lines could change.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this regex to capture `vlan_number` and `ports`,

```
(?m)^(\d+)|(Et\d+\/\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/P074q8/7)

In python,

```
ss="""1    inside                           up        Et0/1, Et0/3, Et0/4, Et0/5

                                            Et0/6, Et0/7

2    outside                          up        Et0/0

3    dmz                              up        Et0/2"""

regx= re.compile(r'(?m)^(\d+)|(Et\d+\/\d+)')
vlan=""
for m in regx.finditer(ss):
    if m.group(1): vlan=m.group(1)
    if m.group(2):
        print("VLAN {} {}".format(vlan, m.group(2)))
```

Output,

```
VLAN 1 Et0/1
VLAN 1 Et0/3
VLAN 1 Et0/4
VLAN 1 Et0/5
VLAN 1 Et0/6
VLAN 1 Et0/7
VLAN 2 Et0/0
VLAN 3 Et0/2
```

**Edited** for viewing input text variable `"ss" value` which is excluded in my previous answer for `readability`.

Comment: That is almost exactly what I need.  But Et0/6 and Et0/7 do not show a vlan.  I tried this, but no luck.    vlan=""
  for m in regx.finditer(line):
   if m.group(1): 
    if m.group(1).strip!="":
     vlan=m.group(1)
    else:
     vlan=vlan
   if m.group(2):
    print("VLAN {} {}".format(vlan, m.group(2)))

Comment: But it seems still output `all what you want`, not any item excluded in my script execution' output. `Of course, 'Et0/6" and "Et0/7" are also showed in the output` as the above answer's output. For your reference, I added the input part `"ss" varible value` which is excluded in my previous answer for `readability`. Please re-check it again. Thank you:-)

Comment: That's it. see ya:-)

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here is that there is not a clear delimiter between each VLAN. However, if we could assume that the VLANs will always have a status of `up`, then the output could be hacked together programmatically as follows:

```
vlan_id = 0
for vlan in txt.split('up'):
    for port in re.findall(r'(Et\d/\d)', vlan):
        print('Vlan {} {}'.format(vlan_id, port))
    vlan_id += 1
```